# Matlab: Find points within a certain range in an array and their order/location in the array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've an array

```
X = 
10
5 (e)
20
5
30
6
40
4
50
3
60
8
70
12
```

and so on...

I already know the value 5 which I've called e. I also know where it is located in the array. I want the following:

1. all the elements in X(2:2:end) within a certain range of +/-3 from e. (which are 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 8).
2. the corresponding X(1:2:end) to the values we found within range. That means the final answer Y should be:

   ```
    Y = 
    10
    5
    20
    5
    30
    6
    40
    4
    50
    3
    60
    8
   ```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should show a little effort with your problem. Provide your current implementation so that we can discuss it and help you.

Comment: Please note that you should make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
         X = [10; 5; 20; 5; 30; 6; 40; 4; 50; 3; 60; 8; 70; 12];
         Xodd=X(1:2:end);
         Xeven=X(2:2:end);
         i=find(Xeven>5) %just an example could be done with other conditions 
         t=[Xodd(i) Xeven(i)];
         %cascade them back!
         Y=t';Y=Y(:);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB/Octave, you can find the indexes of non-zero elements with the function [find](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). Your problem is easily solved combining `find` with logic operators:

```
Y = X(find(X <= X(2)+3 & X >= X(2)-3));
```

Explained:

```
e = X(2)
X <= e+3   % Produces a Matrix with the element-wise result (1 or 0). The
X >= e-3   % values are determined by the logic operators >= and <=.
find(X)    % Returns a matrix with the indeces of non-zero elements of X.
X(find(X)) % Returns the non-zero elements.
```

Tested in Octave (though should work in MATLAB too).

Comment: Although my answer outputs the same `Y` matrix you provided in your question, I've edited it to provide more details. You should consider carefully reading the FAQ to understand what this site is for. You showed little to no effort and didn't explain clearly and accurately what exactly did you need in your question.

Comment: Carles thanks for your effort but I'm not sure how you're getting Y in my question, Your code gives   Y = [5; 5; 6; 4; 3; 8] only! I need the elements in X(1:2:end) as well! this is explained very clearly and accurately in the question.

Comment: Anyone doesn't understand and willing to help please do ask. I think my question is very clear and I've a clear input and a clear output!